# chrome.extensions.onRequest.addListener won't debug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I've searched everywhere for a solution to this...even Google's own code example doesn't work. Someone please explain to me how to debug into event listeners or at least how to make `Console.Log()` work!

Looking at Google's example : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Here is what I'm testing...on my background.js (referenced from my background.html) I have this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ? "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url : "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  });
```

On my popup.js (referenced from my popup.html) I have this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

Considering I have the following permissions in my manifest:

```
"permissions": ["http://*/", "tabs"],
```

and my content scripts are defined as such:

```
 "content_scripts": 
 [
  {
   "matches":   ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
   "js":    ["scripts/background.js"],   
   "all_frames":  true
  }
 ]
```

why am I not able to get any information from console.log or debug into the event? I get the response just fine...but I can't debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an ooooollld question, but for anyone who has the same question: go to chrome://extensions/ (or Tools->Extensions), enable debug view, and then there should be a link under your unpacked loaded extension to inspect the background.html view, which is where console messages from background.html are output.